# How to connect to deployed grpc-server by ip address and host

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

I want to connect to deployed grpc server
by given ipaddress and host like 192.168.0.1:50032 
i tried many stuff but as i checked grpc recommendation to 
have grpc client but i want to try how to post via postman or any 
by grpc interfaces server. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

```
conn, err := grpc.Dial("192.168.0.1:50032")
if err != nil {
    ...
}
```

[Here's a basic tutorial](https://www.grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/go/) you should follow

Comment: My problem is the grpc server was deployed and need to connect to the ipaddress and host only like this post. https://medium.com/@jnewmano/grpc-postman-173b62a64341

Answer (score 1):

Basically you're not able to post GRPC request via Postman, because GRPC messages are binary (protobuf-serialized), while Postman is designed to work only with plain HTTP requests. You'll have to deploy some kind of [proxy](https://medium.com/@jnewmano/grpc-postman-173b62a64341) in front of your service in order to use Postman.

From my point of view, it's much easier just to write your client that fits your needs. The greatest part of job is already done by `protoc-gen-grpc`, because it generates client API, and you need just to build request and send it.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use http client to send requests against http2 server, but you can do it with any of available h2 client tools.. For example `https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/command_line_tool.md`.

Comment: thanks i will try this tomorrow and will let you know @ArkadyB hope this works

Answer (score 0):

@Eli Bendersky : Setting up the client side answer my question also 
this code I used

```
conn, err := grpc.Dial("192.168.0.1:50032", grpc.WithInsecure)
```

Thank you for your help.